# Branch cut for $\sqrt{z^2-a^2}$ in the lower half of the complex plane (instead of $[-a,a]$) - How does this change the function?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, contour-integration, complex-integration, branch-cuts

I have given a function $\sqrt{z^2-a^2}$ with $a>0$.

At first i have chosen the branch cut on the real axis at $-a<z<a$: $$f(z)=\sqrt{z-a}\sqrt{z+a}=\sqrt{|z-a||z+a|} \exp({i\frac{\theta_1+\theta_2}{2}})$$

My question is: What happens, if i turn the branch cuts by $\frac{\pi}{2}$ to $\{ z=\pm a -iy,\ y>0\}$? And how does this change the (value of the) function?

[Change of the branch cut(s)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/37QDO.jpg)

Naively i would assume for the square root function $\sqrt{z} \rightarrow e^{i \pi /4}\sqrt{z}=\sqrt{iz}$ , which leads to $$f(z) \rightarrow g(z)=i\sqrt{z-a} \sqrt{z+a}=\sqrt{{a^2-z^2}}$$

$ $

This problem is part of an exercise:
By changing the branch cuts $$R(z)=A\left[z-\sqrt{z^2-a^2}\right] \rightarrow \tilde{R}(z)$$ $$h(z)=\frac{1}{z-\epsilon-\tilde{R}(z)}$$ and the function $h(z)$  has a pole at $z=E_0-i \Gamma /2$.

Comment: IMO changing the branch cut isn't meaningful, the important concept being the analytic continuation of a given $f$ over some curve $\gamma$. By definition all the branches are obtained this way.

Comment: what happens when continuing (a given branch of) $\sqrt{z-c}$ analytically over some curve ? So  what happens to $\prod_j \sqrt{z-c_j}$ ? In your image look at the white area where the function is analytic, not at the branch cuts.

Comment: For a fixed choice of branch cut for $\sqrt{\cdot}$, $\sqrt{x^2 - a^2} \neq \sqrt{x - a} \sqrt{x - a}$.

Comment: @reuns As long as the curve does not cross the branch cuts, nothing should happen?

Comment: Assuming that your redefinition doesn't change the value at $z = i$, the value will not change anywhere on the upper half plane, or on the portions of the lower half plane outside the strips (with $|\Re z| > a$). On the strip ($|\Re z| < a$ and $\Im z < 0$), the value will change by one period.